# Why doesn't my ProxyPass respect case sensitivity?

Tags: apache2, mod-proxy

Everything i've read suggests that this should pass through a request from localhost/FlowerFoo/flower/bar to localhost/flower/bar

```
SSLEngine on
SSLProxyEngine on

SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

ProxyPreserveHost on

ProxyPass /FlowerFoo/flower https://localhost:8444/flower/
ProxyPassReverse /FlowerFoo/flower https://localhost:8444/flower/
```

If I change FlowerFoo to Flowerfoo, works fine.

If I change FlowerFoo to flowerfoo, works fine.

Does anyone have a decent suggestion as to why this is the case? I've got a feeling its something to do with the reverse rule but am not sure how to prove it.

apache 2.4.12 ( Ubuntu )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of this in the end wasn't related to the rules posted here, but the number of cookies that were being send through apache, which blew up the max cookie length in apache ( 8kb ).

I guess there were some additional cookies Specifically sent on the FlowerFoo path.

I also found enabling mod_log_forensic really helpful in figuring out the cause of this.